# Find Index where Two Arrays have same Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have two arrays, in Javascript:

```
let arr1 = ["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey", "Zebra", "Goat", "Goose"];
let arr2 = ["Zebra", "Goat"];
```

How can I find the indexes of the larger array where there is a match and store them in another array so example output would be:

```
let indexes = [3,4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr1 = ["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey", "Zebra", "Goat", "Goose"];
let arr2 = ["Zebra", "Goat"];
let indexes = []

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(arr2.includes(item)){
    indexes.push(index)
  }
})

console.log(indexes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the expected output using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
let arr1 = ["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey", "Zebra", "Goat", "Goose"];
let arr2 = ["Zebra", "Goat"];

const findIndexes = (param1, param2) => {
  let arr1 = [...param1];
  let arr2 = [...param2];
  //swap the arrays if the no.of array elements 
  //in the second array are greater than first
  if(arr1.length < arr2.length) {
    [arr1, arr2] = [arr2, arr1];
  }
  //Loop through all the items of the smaller array
  //check if the element is present in the bigger array
  return arr2.map(a2 => arr1.findIndex(a1 => a1 === a2));
}

console.log(findIndexes(arr1, arr2));

//here for "test", we'll get index as -1, because
//if the matching element is not found, findIndex will 
//return -1
let arr3 = ["Cat", "Goose", "test"];
console.log(findIndexes(arr3, arr1));
```

If you wish to get the indexes of the elements that are found and wish to filter out all the `-1`s, below is the code for the same.

```js
let arr1 = ["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey", "Zebra", "Goat", "Goose"];
let arr2 = ["Zebra", "Goat"];

const findIndexes = (param1, param2) => {
  let arr1 = [...param1];
  let arr2 = [...param2];
  if(arr1.length < arr2.length) {
    [arr1, arr2] = [arr2, arr1];
  }
  return arr2.map(a2 => arr1.findIndex(a1 => a1 === a2)).filter(ele => ele !== -1);
}

console.log(findIndexes(arr1, arr2));

let arr3 = ["Cat", "Goose", "test"];
console.log(findIndexes(arr3, arr1));
```

Comment: this is a nice - but it doesnt handle missing elements.  i guess filter out the -1?

Comment: @akaphenom, Intentionally I haven't removed -1 for the missing elements. If the corresponding element is not present, those many -1's will be there in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by mapping over your search-teams (`arr2`) and then using the `findIndex` Method on the source-array (`arr1`) like this:

```js
let arr1 = ["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey", "Zebra", "Goat", "Goose"];
let arr2 = ["Zebra", "Goat"];

const result = arr2.map(searchTerm => arr1.findIndex((compareTerm) => compareTerm === searchTerm));

console.log(result);
```